# Is it possible to capture W-Fi direct frames?

Tags: ieee-802.11

Wi-Fi direct (ad-hoc) can transfer data without using an AP.  Is it possible to use my wireless USB adapter to capture frames?

Answer (score 1):

If your USB adapter supports monitor mode, you can capture the Wi-Fi frames that it sees, but those frames may (probably) be encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Wireshark to capture network traffic on an interface, but some adapters will not show you frames other than your own, and without the physical layer.

If you're running ***Linux***, you may want to look at cards with Atheros chipsets, which have a good reputation. If you run ***Windows***, AirPCAP adapters will be good as well.